# How to mimic while($string=~/regular_expression/g) of Perl in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, cycle

I want to mimic

```
while($string=~/($regular_expression)/g){
  print $1."\n";
}
```

of Perl in Ruby.

Is there a way to do that in Ruby (e.g. print something per match)?

Comment: Not all rubbists know python. Could you please tell what this code is supposed to do?

Comment: Nor Perl.  Does it print every match?

Comment: Ok, the code is supposed to print something per match. Is there a way to do so in Ruby?

Comment: For those who want to try out the Perl code: http://codepad.org/zEuQvT7M

Answer (score 1):

To print each match in a string:

```
string = 'abc'
regex = /./

string.scan(regex) {|x| puts x}
```

Output is:

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: No thanks needed.  Accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Looking at your question history, you've asked 14 questions which all have at least one answer and you have never accepted any of them. You can accept an answer by clicking the check-mark next to it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: How about just: `puts string.scan regex`